# asp web application that simultaneously takes in charges multiple accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, api

Hello i'm trying to make  an asp web application that send SMS to registered users whenever they receive an email , I'm a beginner when it comes to coding so I can't think of a pratique way to make it do that.

I thought of adding a timer and making it check every 5 minutes in the sql database for every user if there was something new  but this will make the application slow assuming we have hundred of users.

I  also thought of adding a trigger in the database and having it do the work but I can't find how to use sql trigger in visual studio, any Ideas that could help me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought of adding a timer and making it check every 5 minutes in the sql 
>   database for every user if there was something new but this will make
>   the application slow assuming we have hundred of users ,

Why? Because I do not see that. Except slow means an average delay of 2.5 minutes. Then check every minute. Average delay down to 30 seconds.

> I also thought of adding a trigger in the database and having it do the work but 
>   I can't find how to use an sql trigger in visual studio , any Ideas that could 
>   help me ?

Finding triggers? LEARN YOUR TOOLS. Seriously. But I personally would fire anyone using a trigger to then call an external program to send the SMS - the database is NOT where you want this.

Want it fast? Use a trigger to write a message to message broker (in sql server, it is a subsystem you likely do not know about because of not reading the documentation).

Have your app having some threads wait for messages there. There IS a special syntax to wait until a message arrives.

Voila, case closed.

Comment: I'm sorry but I clearly said I was a  beginner , I appreciate your criticism but you didn't really make it any easier , I still can"t figure how to correct what you pointed to be wrong .

Comment: Well, there is a HUGH difference between being a beginner, and being too lazy to look up the terms in the documentation. The first I help - the second I scourn. Did you ever read the documentation, front to back? Because that is what a beginner should do.

Answer (score -1):

May I suggest that you split up your code, put a message on a queue with the recipient and content of the SMS, and then create a separate webjob/service that subsbcribes to that queue and sends SMS whenever there is an entry there.

This gives you a clean separation of concerns, and removes the need to do polling to the database.

A couple of queues that are nice and easy to get started with:

- Azure Storage Queue
- Azure Service Bus Queue

Comment: I"m sorry i'm not quite sure if I understood what you meant , I'm just reading about the azure storage queue but I'm not getting how I should use it effectively

Comment: And reason to add additional components instead of using sql server doing the same thing?

Comment: In your application, whenever something happens that makes you want to send an SMS, simply put that piece of message in a queue. Then, on the subscriber side, all you have to do is to listen those messages and transmit the contents in SMS. Which part is unclear?